# Data Structures having trouble with limited items sorted

Tags: java, data-structures

I was playing around with such data structures in Java i figure out how to sort items on an Array or to an object. I want some words to be in spesific order I m able to use Bufferedreader HashMap, ArrayList. What i want to do is at any point after reading the first 42 lines, if some line is blank (i.e., a string of length 0) then output the line that occured 42 lines prior to that one. Also how can change this program to read the entire input one line at a time and then output the even numbered lines (starting with the first line, line 0) followed by the odd-numbered lines..I posted the code that i have so far.

```
public static void doIt(BufferedReader r, PrintWriter w) throws IOException {

    ArrayList<String> s= new ArrayList<String>();

    String line;
    int n = 0;
    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
        s.add(line);
        n++;
    }
    Collections.sort(s);

    Iterator<String> i = s.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        w.println(i.next());
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        BufferedReader r;
        PrintWriter w;
        if (args.length == 0) {
            r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            w = new PrintWriter(System.out);
        } else if (args.length == 1) {
            r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
            w = new PrintWriter(System.out);                
        } else {
            r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
            w = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(args[1]));
        }
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        doIt(r, w);
        w.flush();
        long stop = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("Execution time: " + 10e-9 * (stop-start));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
        System.exit(-1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but I hope this can help:

for printing the line that occurred 42 lines before an empty line, you can just keep a counter and once you find a line with zero length, output the line which have the index `counter - 42` ( I might have an off by one error here )

```
     int n = 0;
        while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
            if (n > 42 && s.length == 0)
                 System.out.println(s[n-42]);            
            s.add(line);
            n++;
        }
```

and for printing the even lines first then the odd ones, you can try reading two lines at a time, save the first line into an ArrayList, and the second line into a different one.

at the end, one will have the odd lines and one will have the even lines.

and one more last note, instead of using this:

```
 Iterator<String> i = s.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        w.println(i.next());
    }
```

you can simply use this:

```
for( String line : s)
    System.out.println(line)
```